# imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.icolauncher.io:993/imap/ssl} Certificate failure

Tags: php, laravel, email, certificate, imap

Webklex \ IMAP \ Exceptions \ ConnectionFailedException
imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {mail.icolauncher.io:993/imap/ssl}. Certificate failure for mail.icolauncher.io: self signed certificate: /emailAddress=ssl@myserver.icolister.io/CN=myserver.icolister.io

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For development mode only add this code in your .env file

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=NULL
```

Comment: Hey bro,i added this code i n.env file. but still getting the same issue. please help me.

Comment: Check here for help https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap/issues/67#issuecomment-375041000